# vuejs form data sent via api not visible on laravel controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.6

have a look

**vuejs**

```
data() {
    return {

     url: '/api/client/document/upload',

        }
    },
```

**computed**

```
attachment() {
            return  {
                slug: 'testing',
                test_type[enter image description here][1]: (this.individual === 1)? 'transfer_individual': 'transfer_corporate',
                application_id: this.client_investment_id
            };
```

**upload method**

```
upload: function () {

            if(!this.validateForm()) {
                Message.warning({ message: 'Complete the form and proceed' });
                return;
            }

            if(!this.$refs.upload.uploadFiles[0]) {
                Message.warning({ message: 'Upload the form and proceed' });
                return;
            }

            console.log('data', this.attachment);

            this.$refs.upload.submit();
        },
```

controller side laravel

```
 public function uploadDocument()
 {
    $input = request()->all();

    dd($input);
 }
```

there is a file am uploading to the given url;

when i dd from the controller i get an application_id of null but if i console.log before the submittion am able to view my data. what may i be doing wrong.

[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRc3Y.png) 
[dd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTshR.png)

Comment: Please show the code of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the request as parameter to the function and call the `all()` method on the request instance.

```
 public function uploadDocument(Request $request)
 {
     $input = $request->all();

     dd($input);
 }
```

To take and save file with its name concatenated with a timestamp in public/images folder try

```
//Assuming you have the file input name as `photo` 
if ($file = $request->file('photo')) {

  $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $file->move('images/', $name);

}
```

Comment: sorry still null

Comment: Then the file is not being sent to the controller. In that case try `console.log()` of the variable `this.$refs.upload.uploadFiles[0]` to see if you get a file logged.

Comment: note the file is being sent...the problem is the attached data...one is displaying null on server side the application id

Comment: i have noted that i set the application_id to be set to the store when client applies, but now am dealing with edit, its taking the default state of the application_id which is null

Answer (score 0):

this is the form ...note its taking with it the attachment data from computed property..

```
 <el-upload
                    class="upload-demo"
                    drag
                    :action=url
                    ref="upload"
                    :data=attachment
                    :headers="defaultHeaders"
                    :on-error="errorOnUpload"
                    :on-success="showUploadSuccess"
                    :accept=extensions
                    :thumbnail-mode="false"
                    :auto-upload="false">
            </el-upload>

<el-button type="success" size="mini" @click="upload" class="el-icon-upload">upload</el-button>
```

i have noted that i set the application_id to be set to the store when client applies, but now am dealing with edit, its taking the default state of the application_id which is null